# How to list all recipes used to build an image in Yocto build?

Tags: yocto, openembedded, yocto-recipe

For listing all the recipes which are used to build an image, suggest any method? I had tried following command:

`bitbake-layers show-recipes --filenames`

But the above command has the limitation that it list all the recipes available under yocto directory instead all the recipes used to build an image.

Answer (score 1):

```
bitbake -g <recipe>
```

This will write a file called pn-buildlist that is the complete list of recipes to be built.